Is there an analytical solution for the integral of a ratio of sin functions like this one?
Has anyone encountered the following integral ?:
$$
I =
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin\left(ax\right)}{\sin\left(bx\right)}\,{\rm d}x
$$
Besides the numerical computation, is there a general analytic solution ?.

For many cases, e.g. $a=2,b=3$, WA says the integral doesn't converge. (I wonder which are such cases, generally?)

@r.e.s. It won't converge if the denominator is zero when the numerator is not, and this is probably an equivalence.

@J.S. Right, I should have said "for which $(a,b)$ is this the case?" -- i.e., for which the denominator is zero when the numerator isn't.

Unless $a,b$ are special values, the integrand will not be related to the upper limit $\pi/2$.  So this definite integral will likely be as difficult as the indefinite integral.

@r.e.s. Whenever $b<2$, or for $b \ge 2$, $a$ is an integer multiple of $b$, I think?

I see.  I naively thought there might be a general approach.  I'm interested in two situations: 1)  a = c, b = (1-c) and 2) a =  (2-c), b = (1-c), for 0< c < 1.  thanks all.

I tried it on Desmos. If $|b|\geq2$ it seems to diverge everywhere. That's likely because at $|b|=2$ we gain a second asymptote for our function. But when $0<|b|<2$, it seems to converge for every real value of $a$.

@r.e.s. To explain my reasoning fully: it is an equivalence. For the forwards direction, we note integrals over poles of order $1$ are divergent, while for the converse, we can use l'Hopital's rule. If $b < 2$, we have no zeros in the denominator except for $x = 0$, which is also (always) a zero for the numerator. For $b \ge 2$, we note that $\frac{\pi}{b}$ must be a zero for $\sin(ax)$, which means exactly that $\frac{a \pi}{b} \in n \pi$, so it is necessary that $a$ is an integer multiple of $b$; this is also clearly sufficient. (I have taken $b > 0$ WLOG).

@pstall : You really should edit the constraints on $a$ and $b$ in terms of $c$ into your Question since that's your actual question.

If $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary, there's nothing special about $\pi/2$, and you're basically asking for an antiderivative of $\sin(ax)/\sin(bx)$.  This probably does not have a "closed form": it certainly is not elementary.
On the other hand, if $a$ is a positive integer and $b=1$, you can use
$$\sin(ax)/\sin(x) = U_{a-1}(\cos(x))$$
where $U_n$ are Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind.  If $a$ is odd, the integral is $\pi/2$, if
even it seems to be
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin(2nx)}{\sin(x)} \; dx = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{2 (-1)^i}{2i+1} $$

From OP's comments to the question:
Let $0<c<1$.  Then (via Mathematica 12.3),
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\pi/2}\; \frac{\sin(c x)}{\sin((1-c)x)} \,\mathrm{d}x &= \frac{-1}{2-2c} \left( (2-2c) {}_2 F_1\left(1, \frac{1}{2-2c}; 1+\frac{1}{2-2c}; -\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\pi c} \right) - \right. \\
& \left. \mathrm{i}\pi \cot\left(\frac{\pi}{2-2c}\right)+\left(-\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\pi c}\right)^{1/(2-2c)} \mathrm{B}_{-\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\pi c}} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2-2c}, 0 \right) \right)  \text{,}
\end{align*}
where $B_z(a,b)$ is the incomplete beta function and ${}_2 F_1(\vec{a}; \vec{b}; z)$ is a generalized hypergeometric series and
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\pi/2}\; \frac{\sin((2-c) x)}{\sin((1-c)x)} \,\mathrm{d}x &= \frac{-1}{2-2c} \left( \left(-\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\pi c} \right)^{1/(2-2c)} \left( \left(-\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\pi c}\right)^{1/(c-1)} \mathrm{B}_{-\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\pi c}} \left( 1+\frac{1}{2-2c}, 0 \right) + \right.\right. \\
&\left.\left. \mathrm{B}_{-\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\pi c}} \left(\frac{-1}{2-2c}, 0 \right) \right) - \mathrm{i}\pi \cot\left( \frac{\pi}{2-2c} \right) \right)
\end{align*}
It's plausible that there are only a finite number of typo's in the above.
I have no idea how to generate these results by hand.  I suspect Mathematica used a contour integration based on the appearance of $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\pi c}$ and the $\mathrm{i}\pi\cot(\dots)$s.
P.S. Although these are "analytic solutions", it's not clear that they are in any way useful.  These were generated via
Assuming[{0<c<1},
  FullSimplify[
    Integrate[
      Evaluate[FullSimplify[
        Sin[a x]/Sin[b x] /.{a -> c, b -> 1-c}]],
      {x, 0, Pi/2}]]
]

and then the same thing, but with the rewrite rules changed to
... /. {a -> 2-c, b -> 1-c}]],


@E.T. T.Y. for your input.  These particular integrals arise in an entropy calculation I'm pursuing through the Boltzmann formulation.  I do not have access to Mathematica, but would like to evaluate your result.  I think the second vector input to the generalized hypergeometric function is not complete.  Can you supply the correction?

@pstall : It's a ${}_2F_1$, so $\vec{a}$ has two elements and $\vec{b}$ has one -- and I see "two elements, semicolon, one element, semicolon, argument", so the vectors are complete.

@pstall : Worth understanding https://dlmf.nist.gov/16.2#iii to know that this ${}_2F_1$ is convergent for all $0<c<1$, but convergence would fail if $c$ were an odd integer.  Analytic continuation can give different values at the same input, so it's possible that the expression in this Answer gives values from a branch different than the one you want.  If you want to take the limit $c \rightarrow 1$, start here.

@pstall you can use Mathematica free online

lets use Euler's formula So
$$ I(a,b)=2i \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{e^{-bix}}{1-e^{-2bix}} \sin (ax)dx$$
So the converge of integral is when $b\in (-2,2) , b\ne 0$ So
$$ I(a,b)=2i\sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{-bi(2k+1)x} \sin (ax)dx$$
and since $I(a,b)$ is real So we can take real part only So
$$ I(a,b)=2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin(b(2k+1)x) \sin (ax)dx$$
now if $a\ne n b , n\in N$ we have
$$ I(a,b)=2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{b \sin(\frac{\pi}{2}a)\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}b(2k+1))-a \sin(\frac{\pi}{2}b(2k+1))\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}a)}{a^2-b^2(2k+1)^2}$$
I don't have ideas to simplify this series but maybe we can use some special functions to get the closed form for that
but for $a=nb , n\in N=\{1,2,3,...\}$ we have
$$ I(nb,b)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1-e^{-2bnix}}{1-e^{-2bix}} e^{(nb-b)ix} dx=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{-2bk ix} e^{(nb-b)ix} dx$$
So by taking real part
$$ I(nb,b)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos\left(bx(n-2k-1)\right)dx$$
So
$$ I(nb,b)=\frac{1}{b}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}b (n-2k-1)\right)}{n-2k-1}$$
note : take limit when $k=\frac{n-1}{2}$
for example if $b=1 , a=2n$ we get
$$ I(2n,1)=\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1} \frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} (2n-2k-1)\right)}{2n-2k-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1} \frac{(-1)^{n-k-1}}{2n-2k-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{2(-1)^{k}}{2k+1}$$
which is same results given in the answers

T.Y. for your result.  I will evaluate the series as far as reasonable with some specific values for a and b.
